# Checkboxes are disappearing onclick of the (+)node of tree

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

This is a strange problem I recently faced. I am able to create check-boxes for my tree but it vanishes when I expand the tree nodes by clicking (+) of the tree folder hierarchy. Can someone suggest how can I rectify this issue for my below code?

Comment: Have you tried examining the DOM node? Maybe it's not correctly re-rendered or overwritten by another element. Is there an error thrown? Is the labelNode now empty?

Comment: I checked the label nodes using an alert message, it is not empty. It is prompting every foldername.To my surprise even firebug is not throwing any error.I removed the publishing piece of the code as well to see if it is getting impacts of overriding but the result was same. I have attached my entire code in above post, it will open in IE(on opening in HTML allow the active x popup). Is there something appearing incorrect in my above code?it will be great if you can suggest in my above code.It will open correctly in html.

Comment: I fixed this issue by using cb tree implementation. Checkbox is a very rare topic we make use of in dojo tree and is a bit tricky to achieve.